# Creating summary table of user event data

Tags: r, sum, data.table, aggregation

**Edit 2:** I realized I can use `dcast()` to do what I want to do. However I do not want to count all of the events in the Event Data, only those that happened before a date specified in another data set. I can't seem to figure out how to use the subset argument in `dcast()`. So far I've tried:

```
dcast(dt.events, Email ~ EventType, fun.aggregate = length, subset = as.Date(Date) <= 
as.Date(dt.users$CreatedDate[dt.users$Email = dt.events$Email]))
```

However this doesn't work. I could add the `CreatedDate` column from the `dt.users` to the `dt.events`. And then subset using:

```
dcast(dt.events, Email ~ EventType, fun.aggregate = length, subset = as.Date(Date) <=
as.Date(CreatedDate)
```

I was wondering if it was possible to do this without having to add the extra column?

**Edit:** Just calculated that it'll probably take about 37 hours to complete in the way I'm currently doing it, so if anyone has any tips to make this faster. Please let me know :)

I'm new to R, I've figured out a way to do what I want to do. But it's extremely inefficient, and takes hours to complete.

**I have the following:**

Event data:

```
UserID    Email         EventType    Date

User1     User1@*.com   Type2        2016-01-02
User1     User1@*.com   Type6        2016-01-02
User1     User1@*.com   Type1        2016-01-02
User1     User1@*.com   Type3        2016-01-02
User2     User2@*.com   Type1        2016-01-02
User2     User2@*.com   Type1        2016-01-02
User2     User2@*.com   Type2        2016-01-02
User3     User3@*.com   Type1        2016-01-02
User3     User3@*.com   Type3        2016-01-02
User1     User1@*.com   Type2        2016-01-04
User1     User1@*.com   Type2        2016-01-04
User2     User2@*.com   Type5        2016-01-04
User3     User3@*.com   Type1        2016-01-04
User3     User3@*.com   Type4        2016-01-04
```

Every time a user does something, an event is recorded with an event type, with a time stamp.

User list from different database:

```
UserID    Email         CreatedDate

DxUs1     User1@*.com   2016-01-01
DxUs2     User2@*.com   2016-01-03
DxUs3     User3@*.com   2016-01-03
```

**I want to get the following:**

A summarized list which counts the amount of each event type in the Event Data for each user in the User List. However, events should only be counted if the "CreatedDate" in the user list is before or equal to the "Date" in the Event Data.

So for the above data I would eventually want to get:

```
Email         Type1    Type2    Type3    Type4     Type5     Type6
User1@*.com   1        3        1        0         0         1
User2@*.com   0        0        1        0         1         0
User3@*.com   1        0        0        1         0         0
```

**How I've managed to do it so far**

I've been able to do this by first creating a 'dt.master' data.table that includes all the columns for all events and the list of Emails. Which looks like this:

```
Email         Type1    Type2    Type3    Type4     Type5     Type6
User1@*.com   0        0        0        0         0         0
User2@*.com   0        0        0        0         0         0
User3@*.com   0        0        0        0         0         0
```

And then filling out this table using the while loop below:

```
# The data sets
dt.events # event data
dt.users # user list
dt.master # blank master table

# Loop that fills master table
counter_limit = group_size(dt.master)
index = 1

while (index <= counter_limit) {

    # Get events of user at current index
    dt.events.temp = filter(dt.events, dt.events$Email %in% dt.users$Email[index], 
                     as.Date(dt.events$Date) <= as.Date(dt.users$CreatedDate[index]))

    # Count all the different events
    dt.event.counter = as.data.table(t(as.data.table(table(dt.events.temp$EventType))))

    # Clean the counter by 1: Rename columns to event names, 2: Remove event names row
    names(dt.event.counter) = as.character(unlist(dt.event.counter[1,]))
    dt.event.counter = dt.event.counter[-1]

    # Fill the current index in on the blank master table
    set(dt.master, index, names(dt.event.counter), dt.event.counter)

    index = index + 1
}
```

**The Problem**

This does work... However I am dealing with 9+ million events, 250k+ users, 150+ Event Types. Therefore the above while loop takes HOURS before it has been processed. I tested it with a small batch of 500 users, which had the following processing time:

```
user    system    elapsed
179.33  62.92     242.60
```

I'm still waiting for the full batch to be processed haha. I've read somewhere that loops should be avoided, as they take a lot of time. However I am completely new to R and programming in general, and I've been learning through trial/error and Googling whatever I've needed. Clearly that leads to some messy code. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of something that might be faster/more efficient?

Thanks!

**Edit:** Just calculated that it'll probably take about 37 hours to complete in the way I'm currently doing it, so if anyone has any tips to make this faster. Please let me know :)

**TL,DR:** My event aggregation/summarization code takes several hours to process my data (it's still not done). Is there any faster way to do it?

Comment: you should check long/wide format - `?reshape()`

Comment: I've rolled back the edit as solutions belong in the answers, hope you don't mind

Comment: Furthermore: congrats on your first question on SO! Well formulated and thus an example for all new users imo.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully I'll get the hang of R and be able to contribute to other people's questions soon. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data is already in a `data.table`, you could use the `fun.aggregate` parameter in `dcast`:

```
dcast(dat, Email ~ EventType, fun.aggregate = length)
```

gives:

```
         Email Type1 Type2 Type3 Type4 Type5 Type6
1: User1@*.com     1     2     1     0     0     1
2: User2@*.com     4     1     0     0     1     0
3: User3@*.com     0     1     1     1     0     0
```

---

In response to the comments & updated question: you can get the desired result by using non-equi joins inside the `dcast`-function:

```
dcast(dt.events[dt.users, on = .(Email, Date >= CreatedDate)],
      Email ~ EventType, fun.aggregate = length)
```

which gives:

```
         Email Type1 Type2 Type3 Type4 Type5 Type6
1: User1@*.com     1     2     1     0     0     1
2: User2@*.com     1     0     0     0     1     0
3: User3@*.com     0     1     0     1     0     0
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!

However I still need to make sure to not cast/count all the events, only the ones before the date in the other table. I see that dcast has a subset argument, I'll try to use that!

Comment: Hi Jaap,

I'm trying to use dcast but also subsetting using the other data table. I tried:


`dcast(dt.events, Email ~ EventType, fun.aggregate = length, subset = as.Date(Date) <= as.Date(dt.users$CreatedDate[dt.users$Email = dt.events$Email]))`

This however gives me the following error:
`Error in which(eval(subset, data, parent.frame())) : argument to 'which' is not logical`

I assume because by subset logic is not correct. Is there another way to subset it, or should I add the CreatedDate to the dt.events first, and use that to subset?

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

untested

```
library(dpylr)
library(tidyr)
your.dataset %>%
  count(Email, EventType) %>%
  spread(EventType, n)
```